# How can I add to the contents of UITableView via a button?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have a UITableView subclass which initially holds nothing, however by pressing a button I want to be able to add a string to the data and have it show up in the view. How can I do this? I have been trying to simply modify listdata, but this only seems to work once as after that the Table view does not reload, even though I can see more things are being added to list data. Am I missing something? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

See [Inserting and Deleting Rows and Sections](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/ManageInsertDeleteRow/ManageInsertDeleteRow.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007451-CH10-SW1).

Answer (score 0):

When you have added it to the datasource, call `[yourTableViewObject reloadData];`.